# Always on android/iphone app for corporate tracking

Tags: android, iphone, service

Is it possible to have an application that can be installed that employees would never be able to exit, stop, or uninstall? Or is this something you would have to work out with a hardware vendor/carrier?

Any resources would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to have an application that can be installed that
>   employees would never be able to exit, stop, or uninstall? Or is this
>   something you would have to work out with a hardware vendor/carrier?

From an Android perspective, this would only work if the application were part of the ROM image, otherwise, a normal application can't block itself from being uninstalled.  For this to be feasible, you'd have to create a custom ROM image, root the phone and install the custom image, and then do this for each employee you wanted to track.  It's probably more work than it's worth, but that's the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

**on Android this would be vs the spirit of Android** . What i could tell you is to control whenever the use ends the app , seeing his connection out , and making you pay attention to that bad employee :3

Anyway i tell you to not search more on Android cause there are task killers everywhere . Then it wouldn't be a good research.